# Is redis HINCRBY atomic?

Tags: redis

I want to track inventory state. We are using redis currently in stack.
At present we do this using Postgres. Whenever inventory is in we increment the count and whenever inventory is out we reduce the count. For efficiency purpose I want to try redis HIncrBy.
Is this operation atomic? 
Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Redis is single-threaded, everything is atomic.

Comment: So in essence can redis be used for keeping atomic counters irrespective of which driver I am using e.g Python Driver in Django or Java Driver in Spring..To be more precise underlying threading model of stack I am using

Comment: Correct.  Redis being single threaded means all operations are atomic since there can be no concurrent reads/writes.